# Background location update in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an app which will be used for tracking. For that I want periodic background location update, so I have used background mode location update and background fetch.

Now when the user moves a certain distance my delegate of background fetch i.e. `PerformFetchWithCompletionHandler` gets called but I have to initialize my location object and set a delegate of that inside this method, which didn't work.

```
-(void)entersBackground { 
  [(APP_DELEGATE).locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; 
  __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{bgTask=UIBackgrou‌​ndTaskInvalid; }];
  if (timer) {
    [timer invalidate]; timer=nil;
  }
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTrackingBg) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
} 

-(void)startTrackingBg { 
   [(APP_DELEGATE).locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question by posting your source code.

Comment: After so many research on this i have made some changes in my code now i'm not using PerformFetchWithCompletionHandler delegate but instead of this i'm using background task with one thread which is handling my background location update part but still it is not working for me. Any guidance will be appreciated in advance.

Comment: For your reference here is my code

Comment: -(void)entersBackground{ [(APP_DELEGATE).locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{bgTask=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; }];  if (timer){ [timer invalidate]; timer=nil; }  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
target:self
selector:@selector(startTrackingBg)
 userInfo:nil
 repeats:YES];}
-(void)startTrackingBg
{ [(APP_DELEGATE).locationManager startUpdatingLocation];}